# make sure i've configured dns correctly

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system

On my server with Windows Server 2008, i've added a new zone with my new domain: biografica.ro.

I've added a name server for it: **ns.biografica.ro** and the **ip of the server**.
Also i added two A hosts for **ns.biografica.ro** and **www.biografica.ro**.

I've also defined first that name server on the site where i bought the domain and pointed it to my ip.

Now, i understood that i have to wait 24-48 hours for this new domain to be available online.

Question:
- is this a way to check on the server that i've succesfully configured it?

For instance: *nslookup biografica.ro*
or *nslookup www.biografica.ro*
or *ping www.biografica.ro*

do not work locally, on the server...

Can you give me an advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to talk to your DNS registrar - I can find no evidence that they've notified the .ro registry of the IP address of your name server:

```
% dig +norec @primary.rotld.ro. biografica.ro. ns

; <<>> DiG 9.6.0-APPLE-P2 <<>> +norec @primary.rotld.ro. biografica.ro. ns
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 51884
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;biografica.ro.                 IN      NS

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
ro.                     3600    IN      SOA     primary.rotld.ro. hostmaster.rotld.ro. 2010042929 10800 3600 604800 3600

;; Query time: 58 msec
;; SERVER: 192.162.16.18#53(192.162.16.18)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 29 20:06:35 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 92
```

Comment: Can you please check again with your great command?:)

Comment: yup, looks OK now

Answer (score 0):

To check the respons to a DNS request of a specific server, use "nslookup host dnsserver".

In your situation that could be "nslookup www.biografica.ro localhost" if you are on the server, or "nslookup www.biografica.ro ip_of_server" if you are testing from a client.

However, you do have to add these records at the server that is authoritative for the domain. If you bought the domain then you have to point that to your DNS server.